# Select variable object with counter

Tags: excel, userform, vba

**Background:**

I have a collection of objects (for this example Listbox objects) in a userform using standardized names, I would like to rename them dynamically using a counter cycle.
[image]

**Problem:**

I have not figured a way if what I am asking is even possible, however, I would like to confirm it.
**Solution approach:**

Nothing so far, like I said (refer to the image above) I need a way to set the values of the objects within the for cycle, something like this:

```
For CounterItems = 1 To 18 'Hours in Template
ListBox_Time(CounterItems).Value="Dummy" & CounterItems
Next CounterHours
```

However, I am clueless on how to do so (or if it is achievable).

**Question:**

Is there any way to use a counter to cast a variable/object?

Comment: Depending on how funky you're willing to I remember doing something similar; I created the objects at run-time so they had array like names. Another method would be to make a class wrapper for the objects. Also, I think a collection would work.

Comment: I agree that a collection is the best way to go. Actually I would further say that collections are specifically made to be able to progamatically cycle through its items. Is there not a listbox collection in any case by default in Excel? Pretty sure there is an object collection you can cycle through and test if each item is a listbox and action accordingly.

Comment: I know exactly how to do this, but I want to make sure I get it right: you want to cycle through 18 ListBox objects (named ListBox_TimeX) and rename them to something else, right?

Comment: You will get error 382 - you can't write to a control name while the form is initialized

Comment: @JReid How could you achieve that if the elements are already set on the userform? at.nbayly The thing they are objects in a userforms, but, hmm perhaps you are right, just I need to know somehow how to call the items in the userform at.tyeler Not rename them, instead changing their values

Comment: @Sgdva Oh like set a default value in index 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### For use with ListBox controls on a UserForm

**If you want to change only certain ListBox controls by number:**

```
Public Sub ListBoxNameChange()
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim ctrlName As String, ctrlNum As Integer

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "ListBox" Then
            ctrlName = ctrl.Name
            ctrlNum = CInt(Replace(ctrlName, "ListBox_Time", "")) 
            If ctrlNum > 0 And ctrlNum < 19 Then
                ctrl.AddItem "Dummy" & ctrlNum, 0
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

**If you want to change ALL ListBox controls:**

```
Public Sub ListBoxNameChange2()
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim ctrlName As String

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "ListBox" Then _
            ctrl.AddItem "Dummy" & Replace(ctrl.Name, "ListBox_Time", ""), 0
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes this worked! I go confused somehow because I try to avoid sometimes for each and having a preset cycle instead, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it worked, but I'm not sure how... I wasn't aware it would throw error 382 like Raystafarian said. I guess if you wanted to know how to cycle through userform controls, this does show you how. As far as it being working code.....

Comment: @Sgdva I changed the code to reflect what I think it is you're asking for. Since you didn't actually want to change the objects name, just it's index 0 item, I changed the code to reflect that

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't edit the name while the userform is in use, you'll get [error 382](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251501.aspx)

What you'd like to do is this

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim myForm As UserForm
    Set myForm = UserForm1
    Dim myCtrl As Control
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myCount As Long
    myCount = 1
        For Each myCtrl In myForm.Controls
            If TypeName(myCtrl) = "ListBox" Then
                myCtrl.Name = "Dummy" & myCount 'error
                myCount = myCount + 1
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

But you'll error when you try to write to the name property. You can print the names or set other properties, but this isn't something you can do as far as I know.

Comment: This is a nice tip and it works as well, I upvoted it only but, it might be consider as solution as well (Saddly 2 were given almost in the same time)

Answer (score 1):

I treat them like `Shapes` and test their pre-defined `Names`:

```
Sub ShapeRenamer()
    Dim s As Shape
    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If s.Name = "List Box 6" Then s.Name = "Sixth"
    Next s
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

You would update this to examine the `Shapes` in your userform.

You could also do this with an indexing counter.

Comment: Thanks! However the objects are inside a userform, not in the sheet as shapes; I mean there are list boxes in a userform that I need to work with.