# in vba, How can I get access to the textbox name in a textbox_change sub?

Tags: vba

I have a userform with 70 textboxes and want make sure numerical data in entered by the user.  I want the textbox_change sub to self refer to its name and sue the name in sub that porcessess the error with a message box.  Is this doable?

Code: (# = a variable integer that is appended to end of "TextBox")

```
Private Sub Textbox#_change()

     IF not isnumeric(Textbox#.value) then WrongDataType #
End Sub

Private Sub WrongDataType #

     SendMsg("Please Enter Numerical Data", VBOKonly, "Error")
     TextBox#.value = ""

end sub
```

A message that tells user to enter a number and then empty the text box.

Comment: Inside your subroutine, you can get the object that triggered the subroutine with `Application.Caller`.

Comment: My approach would be similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65895113/4717755) so you only write your validation code once and don't have to recreate it if you add or delete textboxes. It's a clean solution to wrap the textbox control in a class.

Comment: You could also pass the TextBox into WrongDataType.

Comment: PeterT: I thought about waiting till all text boxes were populated and then using "for each..next" to test each one for correct data type.  It seemed better to let the user know immediately, so they didn't have to look for the incorrect box in the form filled with text entry boxes.

Answer (score 3):

Given that the OP has multiple textboxes on the userform, it's advisable to implement shared event code using a class module. This approach not only saves time in terms of code maintenance but also ensures scalability, as the code won't require changes even if the OP adds more textboxes in the future.

- Open Excel and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor.
- In VBE, "Insert" > "Class Module" to create a new class module. Name it "clsTextBox" (or any other preferred name)
- In the class module, add the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents TextBox As MSForms.TextBox
Private Sub TextBox_Change()
    If Len(TextBox.Text) > 0 Then
        If Not VBA.IsNumeric(TextBox.Text) Then
            MsgBox "Input is invalid on " & TextBox.Name
            TextBox.Text = ""
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

- In the UserForm's code window, declare a class object variable and initialize it:

```
Dim TextBoxEvents As Collection
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim TextBoxEvent As clsTextBox
    Set TextBoxEvents = New Collection
    Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
            Set TextBoxEvent = New clsTextBox
            Set TextBoxEvent.TextBox = ctrl
            TextBoxEvents.Add TextBoxEvent
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I run the above code to initialize the user form, I get:

Comment: Compile Error: User_defined type not defined.  With "TextBoxEvent As clsTextBox " highlighted.

Comment: Please follow the procedure to create class module.

Comment: Creating a class module may make sense, but it is often too complicated of a solution for people not already familiar with classes.

Comment: taller_ExcelHome:  OK, I changed the name of the class module to what is in you image above.  I don't get that error anymore. But when I run the userform_initialize sub and test by typing text into a text box, I don't get any kind of error message.

Comment: @braX There's no doubt that it will require some time to learn. When dealing with a substantial number of textboxes like 70, learning and implementing shared event code with a class module becomes highly valuable.

Comment: taller_ExcelHome: I have one text box in this userform that is not subject to "numbers only" entry.  Will this interfere with that text box?

Comment: You could add an extra `If` as `If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
            If ctrl.Name <> "SpecialTextBox" Then`

Comment: Or populate the `Tag` property on the textboxes which aren't numeric-only, and use (eg) `If LCase(ctrl.Tag) <> "text" Then` before adding the textbox to the collection, or move the Tag check to the Class code, so you could perform different types of validation depending on Tag values...

Answer (score 1):

I have decided to put a single validation For each....next loop after all the boxes have been populated.  I will make the bad data boxes turn red, so the user can see which one(s) was in error.

Comment: This way, I will have flexibility to keep some text boxes open for text or text only.

Comment: There are 2 answers that you can use, personally if you expect numbers my suggestion would be [not let them type anything but numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41770674/3221380) and the second if you really need to know the names on the userform, [I did it like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39987351/3221380)